# UiPickerview values displayed as question mark ("?")in swift - But getting the correct value while assigning it to a textBox

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

//I am able to see the correct value in the text box upon scrolling down the picker view. But the picker view display is coming as "?" (question marks). I am confused with where I need to assign the pickerview as input view to the textbox . But still that won't make any sense to the error I am facing right .

I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 3.2.

```
class BillDetailsViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{

  //Variables  Declaration

  //Picker view outlet
  @IBOutlet var datePickerView: UIPickerView!

  //Picker view datasource - integer array
  var integerArray = [Int](1899...2500)

  //Textbox where picked value to be shown
  @IBOutlet var txtPaidYear: UITextField!

  //ViewLoad
  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    datePickerView.isHidden = true
    datePickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    datePickerView.dataSource = self
    datePickerView.delegate = self
    txtPaidYear.inputView = datePickerView
  }

  //picker view delegate functions

  public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return integerArray.count
  }

  public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    let pickerValue: String = String(integerArray[row])
    return pickerValue
  }

  public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    txtPaidYear.text = String(integerArray[row])
    self.datePickerView.reloadAllComponents()
  }
}
```

Comment: I have checked almost all the answers available related to Swift UIPickerView but none of them seems to have the resolution for this . Please help guys

Comment: Sorry I got what you meant . The underscore before pickerview in the method signature I had removed before while trying different solutions over internet .I reverted it back. will change it in the questions also. Thank you for your catch . I think there is something wrong with  txtPaidYear.inputView = datePickerView in the ViewLoad method . its throwing  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: I don't know why my question has been marked as duplicate because the answer its pointing won't solve this issue . That answer says the parameter component is missing in titleForRow delegate function . But thats correct in my code .

Comment: oh...thank you so much . let me correct it . Actually this is the first time I am asking something in stack overflow . Because its the first time I got stuck with something which doesn't have any answer in stack overflow . Thanks much for your help

Comment: no need to reloadAllComponents(). You should only call that if the data source changes. Btw you should declare it as a constant `let integerArray = Array(1899...2500)`

Comment: Not sure but try removing your picker IBOutlet and add `let datePickerView = UIPickerView()` to your view did load method

Comment: You also forgot to set the view controller as the delegate  of your text field `txtPaidYear`

Comment: @Leo : Thank you so much for all the corrections . I tried all those and still the same question mark is coming. But when I choose any question mark the value is correctly gets populated to my TextBox. How strange it is . I even tried adding the pickerview programmatically like you said but same result . really getting mad with this issue ;its almost a day I m behind this :(

Comment: try isolating your issue in a new project. If it doesn't work compress the parent folder into a zip and post the link (dropbox) here I will take a look at it.

Comment: One strange thing I have noticed right now is ; I just tried another project downloaded from some site which is a complete implementation on UIPickerView . But I am getting question mark in that project also . Is it some configuration issue with my system or Xcode ?? Not sure . Thats the one I have tried :   https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/

Comment: Your method signature it is wrong. Should be `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?` But I don't think it will fix the issue. Make sure you are not adding constraints to your picker

Comment: yes. I changed the return type to optional .Is that what you mean ? Also removed all the constraints . Still the same issue  Are we not supposed to add constraints to the picker ? Like you said I will create a new project and try the same .

Comment: It could be adding `???` because of lack of space. If you post the link I can try running it on my machine

Comment: Hi Guys ..Thanks for all your replies . I just removed all the TextView delgates and it worked . Still need to figure out what was the exact issue .So happy that it got fixed . @Leo Dabus: Thank you so much . I just created an independent project like you said and it worked . Thats how I got the idea  of removing the textview delegates . Luckily got worked . 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed all the TextView delgates in the class and it worked . Still need to figure out what was the exact issue . One of the textView delegate method was causing the issue it seems . I need to figure it out.Anyway issue got fixed .I just created an independent project and implemented UIPIckerView for which it was working perfect. Hence I did the same in my project removing all the textview delegate methods . 
Thanks much for all your support .

Answer (score 1):

****You have to change method like this after that it will work definitely.**
and Delete Delegate for TextField which you are using..**

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
}

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int) -> String? {}
```

With:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {}
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.